# Receiving only Array notation to data base for dynamic create input field ,not received input values in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter, dynamic

Here to received array String values, I used dynamically created input fields. I am not getting any error log but after submitting only array notation("[]") is received. At controller, I used **foreach loop**.

**At view Form **
[Dynamically created input field][image]

**At Database received array notation**
[database array notation view][image]

**At view form**

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{

    var services_html = "<tr>"+
    "<td><input name=\"name_ofpost[]\" class=\"form-control name_ofpost service_data\" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"<?php echo display('name_ofpost') ?>\"></td>"+
    
    "<td><input name=\"no_ofpost[]\" class=\"form-control no_ofpost\" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"<?php echo display('no_ofvacy') ?>\" ></td>"+
    "<td  style=\"text-align:center\"><div class=\"btn btn-group\">"+
        "<button type=\"button\" class=\"addMore btn btn-sm btn-success\">+</button>"+
        "<button type=\"button\" class=\"remove btn btn-sm btn-danger\">-</button>"+
    "</div></td>"+
    "</tr>";

    // add more field
    $('body').on('click', '.addMore', function() {
        $("#services").append(services_html);

    });
    // remove field
    $('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
       $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();

    });

});
```

```html
<?php echo form_open_multipart('jobupdate/dailyupdatejob/create','class="form-inner"') ?>
<div>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
     <input name="name_ofpost[]" class="form-control name_ofpost service_data" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo display('name_ofpost') ?>">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input name="no_ofpost[]" class="form-control no_ofpost" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo display('no_ofvacy') ?>">
   </td>
   <td style="text-align:center;">
      <div class="btn btn-group">                                         <button type="button" class="addMore btn btn-sm btn-success">+</button>
        <button type="button" class="remove btn btn-sm btn-danger">-</button>
      </div>
   </td>
 </tr> 
</tbody>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success"><?php echo display('save') ?></button>
<?php echo form_close() ?>
```

**At Controller**

```html
<?php
public function create() 
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('jobtype_id', display('JS_job_type_name') ,'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('jobcategory_id', display('JS_job_category_name') ,'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('status', display('status') ,'required');
#-------------------------------#
$sName = $this->input->post('name_ofpost[]');
$sNo  = $this->input->post('no_ofpost[]');
if(is_array($sName) && is_array($sNo)) { 
$count = count($sName);
$vacancyDtls = array();
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
$vacDtls[$i] = array('name_ofpost' => $sName[$i],
'no_ofpost'   => $sNo[$i]);
}
}
$vacancyDtls = json_encode($vacancyDtls);
 #---------------------------------#
$data['newjobcreate'] = (object)$postData = [
   
'type' => $this->input->post('jobtype_id',true),
'category'  => $this->input->post('jobcategory_id',true),
'vacancy_detail'       => $vacancyDtls,
'created_date'         => date('Y-m-d'),
'status'               => $this->input->post('status',true),
  ]; 
#-------------------------------#
if ($this->form_validation->run() === true) {
if (empty($postData['job_main_id'])) {
if ($this->dailyupdatejob_model->create($postData)) {    
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', display('save_successfully'));
} else {
$this->session->set_flashdata('exception',display('please_try_again'));
}
redirect('jobupdate/Dailyupdatejob/create');
} else {
$data['shorting_list'] = $this->job_bysorting_model->shorting_list();
$data['catagory_list'] = $this->jobcategory_model->catagory_list(); 
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('jobupdate/formoflistofjob',$data,true);
   $this->load->view('padashboard',$data);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things on your controller you need to fix.

First, when you want to retrieve values from the input you only pass the key value you used on the input name. In your case you used on the front-end `<input name="name_ofpost[]" {...}>` so the key you chose is `name_ofpost` instead of `name_ofpost[]`.

In the lines you retrieve the values from the post input remove `[]` from the key name.

```
$sName = $this->input->post('name_ofpost');
$sNo  = $this->input->post('no_ofpost');
```

Second, you used for each on an empty array.

```
$vacancyDtls = array(); //empty array
foreach($vacancyDtls as $vacDtls) {...} //there is nothing to foreach
```

Instead of it, use the count function over $sName or $sNo. Before you use the count function you need to make sure the variable is an array, otherwise, you will get this the warning message you received. You can accomplish that by:

```
    // I assume you need both variables to be on the same size
    if(is_array($sName) && is_array($sNo)) { 
       $count= count($sName);
       $vacancyDtls = array();
       //from here you add a for loop and extract the values from the input variables
       for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
            $vacDtls[$i] = array('name_ofpost' => $sName[$i],
                                 'no_ofpost'   => $sNo[$i]);
        }
    } else {
        //Make sure something came from the post or get resquest you just did from the front-end. 
        var_dump($this->input->post()); // will print every post parameter sent to the controller
        var_dump($sName);
        var_dump($sNo);
    }
```

On the else statement print_r or var_dump the input to check if something came from the request you just executed, this is a way of debugging what you sent to your controller.

Your front-end code does not show how you make the request. It is not clear if you are making an ajax call or using a form, or doing a post or get request. If this is a get request use $this->input->get('key name');

Debug the front-end and make sure the function you use is passing something to the request.

Comment: I am using the only form to insert the values, not using the AJAX . Also, I am trying to use the code what you suggest me.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the form tag? What is the method you are using in the form, post or get? Can you var_dump $this-&gt;input-&gt;post() and $this-&gt;input-&gt;get() and post the results here

Comment: Sir I edited my code. At controller and view section. As you suggest used the code but not receiving the desired results,

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code. System return blank array because you have used $vacancyDtls = array().

Please use below code and let me know.

```
$sName = $this->input->post('name_ofpost');
$sNo  = $this->input->post('no_ofpost');
$vacancyDtls = array();
$count = count($sName);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
            {
            $vacDtls[$i] = array(
                'name_ofpost' => $sName[$i],
                'no_ofpost' => $sNo[$i]
            );
        }
$vacancyDtls = json_encode($vacancyDtls);
```

Comment: error log -- `ERROR - 2018-09-10 07:27:03 --> Severity: Warning --> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable `

Answer (score 0):

`ERROR - 2018-09-10 07:27:03 --> Severity: Warning --> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

**The error** was coming because I have not declared the **array** for the **controller function**. And I had changed my code and it **working fine**.

**Controller function**

```html
//input value from input field
$sName = $this->input->post('name_ofpost');
$sNo  = $this->input->post('no_ofpost');
//declared the array  here
$vacancyDtls = array();
$vacancyDt = array();
//used the count function for array
if(is_array($sName) && is_array($sNo)) {
$count = count($sName);
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
$vacancyDt[$i] = array(
'name_ofpost' => $sName[$i],
'no_ofpost' => $sNo[$i]
);
}
}
//to make the json format to database 
$vacancyDtls = json_encode($vacancyDt);
```

**And the output as**
`[{"name_ofpost":"post1","no_ofpost":"25"},{"name_ofpost":"post2","no_ofpost":"100"},{"name_ofpost":"post 3","no_ofpost":"58"}]`

Thanks : Francisco de Castro

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as correct? I'm glad I was able to help you.

Comment: I had changed your code a little bit and made it correct. Thanks